# Is it possible to have a Lightning component always visible in a lightning app?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I have a Lightning app that uses console style navigation.

Currently I have a Lightning component that pops up from the utility bar, but it's not possible to pin it so that it is always visible.

Is there either a way to make the component always visible, or a way to include a component / Visualforce page in the app so that it is always visible, perhaps a sidebar?

Comment: Alaways visible but where? You can add a component to the utility bar, to a record page or to a lightning page. I don't see any other place in the Salesforce layout.

Comment: Yes I don't know where. I'm more used to the Classic console, where we could just drag a Custom Console Component wherever we liked. Lightning is new to me.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have a full control on the Lightning components placement :(